# How to know PID of the process ran by remote ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

If I run a process at the remote site by using ssh as follows:

```
nohup ssh remote sleep 100 &
```

Is there a way to know the PID of sleep at remote?
Trying echo $! just returns the PID of ssh at local.
And, greping won't work since there are multiple sleep processes at remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a string to `ssh` so try

```
 nohup ssh remote 'sleep 100 &; echo $!'
```

Comment: Thanks! Little bit more what I want is 

nohup ssh remote 'sleep 100 & echo $!' &

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    nohup ssh remote 'sleep 100 > out 2> err < /dev/null & echo $!'
```

Comment: Which does not answer the question, given that the OP told us: *"there are multiple sleep processes at remote."*